# How to merge rows with same id in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have my excel database, and there are several rows with the same id, something like that:

```
id   data    data
a    Tim      Peter
a    Luke     Jim
b    Rob      Tom
b    Alex     Bob
```

I would like to end up with a table like that:

```
id   data           data
a    Tim; Luke      Peter; Jim
b    Rob; Alex      Tom, Bob
```

is that possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible, but not recommended.  Your original setup is already optimal for Excel functions (for example Countif, Sumif, etc).  Why do you want to change the layout to something more difficult to work with?

Comment: Indeed, I have the database where I can work already done, but I want to create a file to show in some presentation, so, just graphical needs. My database has 390 rows, and the IDs are actually 55, so easier to show in a presentation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data starts at A2, and id sorted. You may do :

```
E2  ->  =IF(A3=A2,"",A2)
F2  ->  =IF($A1=$A2,F1& " ; "&B2,B2)
G2  ->  =IF($A1=$A2,G1& " ; "&C2,C2)
```

and drag downwards. Use filter in column E and you'll get the final consolidated table.

Hope it helps. ( :